# c function - call function that has param with no type, and ignore the param

Tags: c

Here is the program:

```
// system call fcntl()

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/*
 * check open file flags.
 * @return 0 on succeed, or errno on failed.
 */
int get_file_flags(sync) {
    char *fp_out= "/tmp/read_terminal.log";
    int fd_out, fd_in;
    fd_in = 0; // read from stdin
    int flag = O_RDWR | (sync?O_SYNC:0) | O_CREAT | O_APPEND; // append & syncusively
    mode_t mode = 0644;

    int fd = open(fp_out, flag, mode);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Failed to open file. Error: \t%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    } else {
        printf("Succeed to open file, file descriptor: %d\n", fd);
    }

    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    if (flags & O_SYNC)
        printf("sync flag set\n");
    else
        printf("sync flag not set\n");

    close(fd_out);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    get_file_flags(0);
    get_file_flags(1);
    get_file_flags();

    return 0;
}
```

Function `get_file_flags` has a param with no type, and it will default to `int` right?
When I call the function without pass the param, it could compile.

I got this by accident, but then I am wondering what happened in this case.

**My question is:**

What value is passed? Is it `NULL`?

Comment: The compiler should give you an error if you try to call a function with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am on linux, with `gcc 4.8.2`, and it did compiled.

Comment: If it compiles without errors, then it's *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Compile properly. `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`: gives `test.c:11:5: error: type of 'sync' defaults to 'int'`.

Comment: Anyway, C11 6.5.2.2/6: `If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *undefined behavior*, quite literally anything can happen.

But what will probably happen in practice is that the compiler will not go out of its way to pass anything to the function, so `get_file_flags` will read whatever value happened to be lying around when you called it.

It's easy to check by just compiling the code and looking at the call site:

```
    movl    $0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    get_file_flags
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    get_file_flags
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    get_file_flags
```

Here you can see your 3 function calls in main. The first two times 0 and 1 are passed, and the third time nothing in particular is passed. The value will be whatever happened to be in `%edi` at this moment.

But again, this is undefined behavior. You should never rely on this or assume anything about what could happen.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass a parameter, since `get_file_flags` uses `sync`. Otherwise you'll have Undefined behaviour. But MSVC gives no warnings or errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_file_flags(sync) {
   printf ("%d\n", sync);
}

int main(void) {
    get_file_flags(5);
    get_file_flags();
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
5
1638280
```